# Selenium TestNG @DataProvider runtime value

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am creating a Selenium Framework which uses the POM structure with TestNG. I am using the `@DataProvider` annotation to pass value to `@Test`.

My question is if output of one `@Test` method is required to be used at later `@Test` method then how will I do that because with data provider I can pass only values that it contains.

Comment: pom framework? I think you mean maven :)

Comment: I personally have answered several questions on this site with the same response.  Don't make your tests dependent on each other. Find out a way to make them self-sufficient.

Comment: Hi sircapsalot, its POM only not Maven

Answer (score 0):

OP does not mention language or need for parallel execution, hence this can be easily solved with a static variable. In Java the below should print pass:

```
public static int outputOfMethodA=0;

@Test
   methodA(){
   outputOfMethodA=outputOfMethodA+1;
}

@Test
methodB(){
   if(outputOfMethodA=1){
   System.out.println("pass!");
   }
   else{system.out.println("fail!")
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**POM he meant was the Page Object Model** type of Mapping for his WebElements.

It is always a good practice to loosely couple your Test Methods(hence result of one @Test shouldn't be depending on another @Test).

Still if you want to achieve it: @DataProvider can be used on any number of @Test methods you have in your Test Class. Just define a class level Map and use this among your test.

Sample:

```
TestingClass{

// define global variable
Map<String,String> resultMap=new HashMap<String, String>();

@DataProvider
public Object{

// some logic for dataProvider
}
@Test(dataProvider="dp")
method1(){

//  your logic
// then put your final result to be used by method2 into appropriate obj               

 resultMap.put("key","value");// assign result to defined global variable

  }

  @Test(dataProvider="dp")
  method2(){

  // use the resultMap to take results from previous method.

  }


  }
```

Comment: OP is not after using dp in every single @Test method; but the result of the first method globally.